# Is it safe to publish an EC2 security group?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Is it safe to publish the security group you're launching machines on? i.e. "my box is on sg-abcdef"

Are there any permissions that control who is allowed to join your SG? Worst case, it seems like a malicious user could start an arbitrary instance, join your SG, then send TCP traffic to ports inside your firewall. Is this correct?

Are there other potentially bad things can a malicious user do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is safe to publish that information. For anyone else to modify or assign that SG to a host, you would have needed to explicitly grant them access (via an IAM user) to do so.

If you spend any time at all in the AWS Developer forums, you'll frequently see AWS staff members asking people for instance IDs, security group IDs, etc., so they can troubleshoot things. AWS staff wouldn't be asking for people to post this information on a public forum if it were risky to do so.